# Result is different in gdb and shell when I execute fork system call

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit
#include <unistd.h> // fork, getpid

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello world (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
    int ret_fork = fork();
    if (ret_fork < 0) {
        // fork failed; exit
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (ret_fork == 0) {
        // child (new process)
        printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
    } else {
        // parent goes down this path (original process)
        printf("hello, I am parent of %d (pid:%d)\n",
           ret_fork, (int) getpid());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

in shell i got

```
hello world (pid:3082)
hello, i am parent of 3083 (pid:3082)
hello, i am child (pid:3083)
```

BUT when i excute 1 line and 1 line 1 line
i got

```
hello world (pid:3082)
hello, i am child (pid:3083)
hello, i am parent of 3083 (pid:3082)
```

why are they different ??

Comment: Is your question why in one case you get the output of the child first and in the other case the output of the parent first? Please copy&paste program and output to your question, don't re-type it. The spelling in the output does not match the program. Please [edit] your question to fix this and to make it more clear.

Comment: Why do you expect the same sequence, as they are separates processes?

Answer (score 2):

You can't determine the order processes will run in. That is up to the OS scheduler. If you want the parent process to wait for the child process you can add `#include <sys/wait.h>` and add `wait(NULL);` before printing "i am the parent"

Read more here: [wait(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html)